# Why does my empty iOS single view app project crash?

Tags: ios, xcode, autolayout

I created a new iOS project based off of Xcode's Single View iOS app template and was very surprised to find that adding a label and 4 basic constraints for the top, right, bottom, left position results in an immediate launch crash.

There is literally nothing else in the project, it is empty, I'm curious what is going on, has anyone else experienced something like this or am I missing something obvious?

[You can find a copy of my current project here.](https://ufile.io/a68nd)

```
Assertion failure in -[UIView _nsis_center:bounds:inEngine:forLayoutGuide:],
/BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/UIKitCore_Sim/UIKit-3698.93.8/NSLayoutConstraint_UIKitAdditions.m:3588
2019-03-13 09:59:07.873433-0600 test[5480:349128] 
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException',
 reason: 'Error in compatibility flow'
```

[image]

Comment: I've never had this happen, but from the assertion message it would appear that there's something wrong with the constraints. It takes a bit of learning and practice to construct constraints that are both complete and solvable. I'd suggest deleting the constraints, then adding them back in one at a time until it either works  or you figure out what the problem is.

Comment: What device are you running this on that produces the error?

Comment: iPhone XR on the iOS Simulator

Comment: @JosueEspinosa I created a fresh project, dragged a label and set the same constraints as you. Then I ran it on the iPhone XR, and others, without encountering the crash. Maybe you could share your project online and we can have a look. Something else must be off. Btw, which Xcode version?

Comment: @JosueEspinosa Checked out your project. Just fyi, it has different constraints than those as described in your question. Anyways, it executed properly here, i.e. no crash here (iPhone XR, Xcode 10.1)

Comment: Try a clean and run after deleting derived data.

Comment: @JosueEspinosa I would love to help. Are you sure there isn't any code you have created? This appears to be a different project to the one in the image.

Comment: @George_E On my machine, the project I linked produces the same error on a orientation change on the iPhone 8 simulator. Latest version of Xcode and iOS. I took the picture before linking the project and then simplified the constraints in an attempt to resolve the error.

Comment: @JosueEspinosa No matter what I try, the error I get is `Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.` using the constraints from **the screenshot**. There must be more constraints that are causing this...

Comment: @JosueEspinosa Your bounty ends in 3 days, you don't have long! Please provide as much information as possible!

Comment: When I run your example project. Everything seems working fine. I think you have problem with ur Xcode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Attached project works just fine, so:

1. Delete content of `/Users/{username}/Library/Developer`
2. Delete Xcode
3. Install new Xcode from App Store
4. Run project

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that you setup those constrains on an iPhone 8, but you are trying to run it on an iPhone XR.

Constraints should not be that specific. Depending on the screen size it’s basically impossible to meet those constraints. How can a constraint be pinned to the top by X pixels and to the bottom by Y pixels and the device height is different than what you originally planned for?

I’m guessing running the app on an iPhone 8 would work correctly.

But the error basically means it can’t satisfy your constraints. Which makes sense since those constraints are impossible with the different screen size of the iPhone XR vs iPhone 8.

If you remove the top or bottom constraint and the left or right constraint, and give it a height and width constraint, it would work. Give it just enough to position itself. But don’t just design for one device. Think about your layout in a fluid manner, not for one device like you did.

Comment: `The problem here is that you setup those constrains on an iPhone 8, but you are trying to run it on an iPhone XR.` Why do so? It's auto layout constraints right.

Comment: It is just a view as option not a property so there is nothing wrong with running it on XR and set view as to iPhone 8

Answer (score 0):

You can add constraints of Width as width >= 0 and height as height >= 21 something like that.

Also clean the project and derived data.